# Upload and preview image with javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to upload a photo and show in a `<img>` but it is not working.
I am working with Python and Django framework and the forms generating automatically as much as the user needs.
My javascript codes are from [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/t6UP5/)

here is my codes, javascript and also html:

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#myimg').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#photoinput").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div name="imageholder" class="row tm-image-holder">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
          <img id="myimg" src="#" style="height: 200px;text-align: center;">
      </div>
  </div>
  <input id="photoinput" type="file" name="photo" href="#"
     class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary inout-margin mybut">
  <input id="name" name="name0" type="text" class="add-input input-margin"
         placeholder="Name, Mohammad, ... *">
  <input id="job" name="job0" type="text" class="add-input"
         placeholder="Job, Developer, Designer, ... *">
  <textarea id="explain" name="explain0" class="add-textarea input-margin" rows="4"
            placeholder="Explain this member in 2 to 4 lines *"></textarea>

</form>
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Are you including jQuery?

Comment: No, it's not showing anythings in <img>

Comment: Add name to image and try to access <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
          <img id="myimg" src="#" style="height: 200px;text-align: center;">
      </div>

Comment: Are you including jQuery? Do you attach the code after the input is rendered on the page? (You do not include jQuery in the snippet above and the code runs after the element in the snippet above)

Comment: @epascarello, No my javascript file is an external js file and i added it to the base.html template.

Comment: Which means nothing to me.... So you do not have a link to jQuery in your page? Is the script located in the head or the body?

Comment: I have this in my head @epascarello , <script src="{% static "myapp/js/photoupload.js" %}">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure that you have jQuery referenced on your page since that code is using it.

Seconds you need to make sure you actually bind the event to the element so you need to wait for it to be there. You can do that by placing the script after the element or call it document ready, or call it on window load.

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#myimg').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$(function () { //document ready call
    $("#photoinput").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div name="imageholder" class="row tm-image-holder">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
          <img id="myimg" src="#" style="height: 200px;text-align: center;">
      </div>
  </div>
  <input id="photoinput" type="file" name="photo" href="#"
     class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary inout-margin mybut">
  <input id="name" name="name0" type="text" class="add-input input-margin"
         placeholder="Name, Mohammad, ... *">
  <input id="job" name="job0" type="text" class="add-input"
         placeholder="Job, Developer, Designer, ... *">
  <textarea id="explain" name="explain0" class="add-textarea input-margin" rows="4"
            placeholder="Explain this member in 2 to 4 lines *"></textarea>

</form>
```

Comment: no change! it is working like before change the codes, thank you

Comment: Well the code works fine in my snippet so without seeing your actual code it is impossible to help you out.